# JSON Web APIs from gRPC Change Swagger Operation Tag

Tags: c#, swagger, grpc, .net-6.0, swashbuckle

i created a web api from a grpc service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/httpapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and started the swagger page:
[image: Swagger]

where can i change the Operation Tag fom the Swagger?
Now the operation tag is generated by **proto filename + service name** (*greet.Greeter1*)

here my swagger options from program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.TagActionsBy(api => new[] { api.GroupName });
    c.DocInclusionPredicate((name, api) => true);
});
```

and in Service:

```
 [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Custom Group Name")]
    public class GreeterService : Greeter1.Greeter1Base
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
```

that gives ne the following result:

[image: Swagger no description]

**How can i change the operation tag and add a description?**

thanks for your help!

Comment: https://rimdev.io/swagger-grouping-with-controller-name-fallback-using-swashbuckle-aspnetcore/

Comment: Not working. System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine tag for endpoint.'